How to copy a .env inside a Dockerfile to a Google Cloud Run instance?
I'm trying to deploy a Docker image with the following content:
COPY .env /

When I try to use the file, I receive this error:

/.env: No such file or directory

I have no .dockerignore or .gcloudignore file and I'm not sure if its because of Docker or Google Cloud.

Are you able to build and run application using Docker cli?
